# Secure Table Operation in Azure Mobile App

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

In Azure mobile service we have to pass key "X-ZUMO-APPLICATION" and value as secret key in request header to perform any SQL Database table operation using WebAPI. One can not access access the table using WebAPI unless they have key.

In Azure mobile app SQL Database table operation can be performed by adding "?zumo-api-version=2.0.0" and it doesn't require any key. How can I secure the table operation using WebAPI in Azure mobile app.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

We got rid of the API key from Azure Mobile Services, because it didn't actually provide any level of security, and perceived security is worse than no security. (Anyone can get your key by decompiling your app, or sniffing network traffic, for instance.)

You should use instead use authentication to secure your endpoint.

See:

- [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-authentication-overview/)
- [Add authentication to your Xamarin.Forms app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users/)

Comment: Thanks Donna! In my scenario I don't use SQL Database table operation using WebAPI from app. I have a web api from that I am performing SQL Database table operation using WebAPI. I was reading the first link you shared in that there is a section "Service-to-service authentication" but it supports only Active Directory. Can 'Service-to-service authentication" be implemented between Web API and SQL Database operation as WebAPI with custom authentication mechanism.

Comment: This sounds like a new question, I would post it with the tags of web-api.